# Django 2.2 error - Integrity Error, NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a sample Django 2.2 project that has a search bar in the top right corner of the nav bar (taken from the Bootstrapers):

**navbar.html**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/search/">Search</a>
  </li>
   ...  
 {% endif %}

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/a/">A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/b/">B</a>
  </li>

  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action = '/search/'>
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
 </div>
</nav>
```

It returns "You searched for [search argument]" to the url '/search/' and works fine. I would like to bring it from the nav bar under the 'Search' menu in the nav bar. I have the following:

**searches/models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.conf import settings

 # Create your models here.
 class SearchQuery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank = True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
 query = models.CharField(max_length=220)
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**searches/views.py**:

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
  from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

  from .models import SearchQuery

  # Create your views here.
  @login_required
  @ staff_member_required
  def search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       user = request.user
    SearchQuery.objects.create(user=user, query=query)
    context = {"query": query}
    return render(request, 'searches/view.html',context)
```

**searches/templates/searches/view.html**:

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}


 {% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<form action = '/search/'>
  <input type="search" name="q" aria-label="Search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-12 col-8 mx-auto'>
    <p class='lead'>You searched for {{ query }}</p>
</div>

</div>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

When I search from the search bar in the navigational pane, it returns the argument. But when I want to run the search from the search bar and click on the Search tab, I get this:

```
   IntegrityError at /search/
   NOT NULL constraint failed: searches_searchquery.query
   ...
    ...searches\views.py in search_view
    SearchQuery.objects.create(user=user, query=query)
```

Why am I getting this ?

**EDIT**:

After making this change in **searches/views.py**:

```
query = request.POST.get('q', None)
```

I get this error in the runtime:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: searches_searchquery.query
```

and in the browser:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems your `q` as query is None. add print statement before `SearchQuery.objects.create(user=user, query=q)` line and check that is empty or not

Comment: @shotgunner 'print(q)' returned "could not identify q", when I replaced all 'q' with 'query', I got 'sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: searches_searchquery.query'. It did not print an output for some reason (I use MINGW64).

Comment: print distinguishable text before it like this:  `print("this is query =>>>>>>" + query)`

Comment: @shotgunner "...searches\views.py", line 15, in search_view
    print("this is query =>>>>>>" + query)", "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Comment: It means that your query is None. Why are you use GET in your code ? you use form in your template it POST its data not GET. change your code to `request.POST.get('q', None)`

Comment: @shotgunner the runtime shows "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: searches_searchquery.query", and the browser points to search_view in views.py: "\searches\views.py in search_view
 SearchQuery.objects.create(user=user, query=query) …
▼ Local vars
Variable Value
query 
None
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/search/'>
user 
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>"

Comment: Add your details to the question. I don't completely understand what you write in the comment

Comment: @shotgunner done

Comment: print both `request.GET` and `request.POST` in your view code to see where is `q` ? Are you fill the input box in the form and then click on the button ?

Comment: @shotgunner no, I don't get to fill the search box out, because the error comes after I click on the Search link in the navigational pane. May be it is expecting the keyword parameter when it loads the search textbox and not getting it?

Comment: @shotgunner the print(query) produces "None" in the runtime.